# Which of these RAM chips can I use, to be compatible?

Tags: memory

A friend bought a new desktop Windows computer. He bought it with only 4GB RAM, and, as you would expect, it runs excruciatingly slowly.

Here is what he has:
[image]

I have the following lying around. I understand that they ought to be of the same generation x for DDRx (e.g all DDR3), and should have matching speeds, but I really want to be sure that I don't make any mistakes here.

Given that he has 2 slots for rAM, which of all of these will give him the maximum compatible RAM size?

Here are mine:
#1 [image]

#2 (I have 2 of these) [image]

#3 [image]

Comment: 46B Ram?  Maybe 4gb ram?   You really need to advise the CPU and motherboard for us to answer you. I dont recognise your second stick,  ut as thr last 2 are PC3 and the original is PC4 I doubt they will work.

Comment: If you're just willing to watch youtube / use MS Office / view web pages / check emails, 4GB RAM would be usually enough. If your Windows 10 is slow, upgrade your HDD to SSD before doing anything else.

Comment: (pipe is mocking you because you wrote 6B instead of GB)

Comment: I do make more typos than the average person, but I doubt if anyone makes none ;-) If it's not clear from the question, then move on to the next question.  If it is clear, why mock (which can lead to a ban)? Upvote to you, though, sir :-)

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica - It's the responsibility of the author not to community editors to ask properly formatted questions.  This includes making sure the question is grammatically correct and has as few spelling errors as possible.  Furthermore, it's not great to ask, for authors to use the appropriate tools to avoid typos given that nearly every browser has a built-in spellchecker. Anyways, was the comment about the typo out of line, it probably wasn't the nicest way to ask if it was a typo or not. As the author, you should have just fixed and flagged it as unnecessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

None of those sticks will work in the new system.

All three sticks you have are "PC3" or DDR3 sticks. The stick in his new system is PC4 - DDR4.

The only stick without it explicitly written on the label is the [Kingston KVR16N11](https://www.kingston.com/datasheets/kvr16n11_8.pdf) which is also still DDR3.

You will not be able to physically fit any of your sticks into the DIMM slots of the new system. They are not compatible and will not work together.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick and definitive answer. I will take the existing stick to a PC shop & see what they have on offer. As he only uses it got email and very occasional MS Word / Excel (a few times per month, if that often), I reckon he can get buy with  16gB

Comment: For such modest use 8 GB will be enough, and perhaps even 4 GB.

Comment: @Mawg: "Get by"? 16 GB for Word/Excel/email is _a lot_. Sure, it's good to have more RAM (especially so that the OS could cache more things), but 8 GB is usually enough for a lot of things and even 4 GB is usable with an SSD _(though it's kinda tolerable with a good HDD too – definitely slow but not yet "excruciatingly slow"; I know quite a few people who use Word/Excel/Outlook on such machines daily...)_ If the new PC has a mechanical HDD, I'd say first move the OS to an SSD, and then upgrade to 8 GB if necessary.

Comment: That sounds like  a great tip. I will check what he has

Comment: @user1686 Wow am I reading a thread from 2011? 4G is only enough for Windows and 1 tab. I upgraded from 8G to 32G a couple of years ago and got a massive productivity boost from not having to close programs. Hell, even phones have 8G RAM these days.

Comment: @Navin - Some phones have 8 GB, newest iPhone only has 6 GB, more accurate statement is that phones have significantly increased their memory capacities in recent years.